# How to change this code with right syntax in to mariaDB?

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

I'm new to this sql functions. I want a customized auto incremented field with the following SQL function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION nextvacancy() returns char(5) as begin
declare @lastval char(5)
declare @i int
declare @newId char(5)

set @lastval = (select max(vacancyId) from vacancy)

if @lastval IS NULL 
    set @lastval = 'V0000'

    set @i = right(@lastval,4) + 1

    set @newId = 'V' + right('000' + convert(varchar(10),@i),4)

return @newId end
```

This worked fine with mssql but in mariaDb server it shows this error.

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @lastval char(5)
    declare @i int
    declare @newId char(5)**

The result should be like this.
[V0001,V0002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrWiB.png)

How can I adapt this code to mDb server?

Comment: This SQL code will **not** work in MySQL.. `CREATE FUNCTION` clause does **[not](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)** contain `AS` keyword in MySQL... This looks to be SQL Server (MSSQL) [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  which does has a keyword `AS`  ...So i changed the tags because it looks like you are convert SQL server (MSSQL) syntax to MariaDB(MySQL) syntax

Comment: Yes. It's mssql

Comment: That's *not* a good SQL Server query. `MAX+1` just begs for integrity errors due to duplicate values. SQL Server has SEQUENCE objects for this job, and so does MariaDB. *In both databases* you can write `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR VacanciesSequence AS VacancyID` to get the next value. Formatting is different for each database. In SQL Server you'd write select `format(someID,'\V0000')` to format a value with a `V` prefix and 4 digits. `select format(next value for vacancies,'\V0000') as NextVacancy`

Comment: In MariaDB you'd probably have to append the `V` prefix explicitly and use `LPAD` for the leading zeroes: `select 'V' + LPAD(next value for vacancies,4) as NextVacancy`.

Comment: Actually I think your real problem is confusing *rendering* with persisted values. You should use a regular auto increment but *render* it with the leading “V”, preferably in the app layer (ie not in any SQL), as the leading “V” has nothing to do with the data or where/how it’s persisted.

Comment: `DELIMITER`; semi-colons; `THEN`; etc, etc.  Study the manual for the syntax.  Study examples throughout this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was **very bad** for Sql Server, too, because it failed to encapsulate the increment/select in a transaction. To fix it for Sql Server, it should be changed to either use an identity column or (even better) a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

And the cool thing is the sequence works in MySql/MariaDB, too. So, to translate this code, first create the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE VacancySeq START WITH CurrentMaxValueHere INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then update the function to pull from the sequence:

```
return next value for VacancySeq
```

I know this will be missing the `V` and leading zeros... but it's a mistake to store those as part of the column value. That's a *formatting* issue, and formatting should be done as much as possible on the client rather than in the DB.